# Drupal 7 & OpenLayers - Can see sample map under OpenLayers Admin: Preview but NOT under Views: Preview

Tags: views, javascript

I'm stumped and seeking some direction.

I'm seeking to create a dynamic map using OpenLayers, Drupal 7, Views and Custom Content Type. I've read all the documentation I can find and so far I've been able to:

- successfully create a content type (using "Geolocation Field" to
  store geodata instead of GeoField),
- create an OpenLayers Overlay in Views, and
- create a custom map (clone of Google Map example) in OpenLayers Admin.

In OpenLayers Admin I can view the sample map ('MySample Map") under OpenLayers Admin: Maps: Edit Map: Preview.  This map successfully shows data points from content in the database.

However when I create a new View of format OpenLayer with style = MySample Map nothing shows - no datapoints and no map, only the title.

Any recommendations for debugging/resolving this problem?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Openlayers is generated via JavaScript so wont display in the views admin. Save your view and check the page/block.

If it is still not working check the width of the map. Sometimes, when set to auto the map will collapse showing nothing. Set a fixed with and check again. If it works then some simple css will fix the rest.

Good luck :)